# Paraview programmatically Save Screenshot not working on an XYChartView

Tags: animation, export, screenshot, paraview

Using ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Paraview 5.0.1.
I have a Layout with two views, one RenderView and one LineChartView.

I want to programmatically Save Screenshot and Save Animation of the two together.
When doing either one, and also when doing this with only the LineChartView, only a portion of it shows up in the created image. The image below shows an example, where the error is evident.

[image]

The same result is obtained when saving the image with:

1. `WriteImage("test.png")`
2. `SaveScreenshot("test.png")`. Tried several combinations of `ImageQuality`, `ImageResolution`, `magnification`.
3. Via menu (not my final target, but I tried it).

**How can I programmatically get the correct images/animations, both of this View alone and paired with another one?**

Comment: ParaView 5.4.1 is the most recent version. Can you try that one? Many bug fixes have been included since 5.0.1, and your problem may be resolved in the newer version.

Comment: @CoryQuammen - 5.4.1 seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by Cory Quammen in a comment, upgarding to 5.4.1 seemed to work.
I wouldn't know if suitably setting some parameters (e.g., `lineChartView1.ViewSize` and/or in `SaveScreenshot`) this could also work in 5.0.1.